# openvpn to AWS VPN endpoint gets a connection reset error

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn

I've setup a new AWS client VPN Endpoint using mutual authentication, and trying to connect using openvpn, I get a connection reset error:

```
2023-07-06 12:44:43 OpenVPN 2.5.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 14 2022
2023-07-06 12:44:43 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
2023-07-06 12:44:43 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]3.65.80.98:443
2023-07-06 12:44:43 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
2023-07-06 12:44:43 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]3.65.80.98:443 [nonblock]
2023-07-06 12:44:43 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]3.65.80.98:443
2023-07-06 12:44:43 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
2023-07-06 12:44:43 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]3.65.80.98:443
2023-07-06 12:44:43 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
2023-07-06 12:44:43 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
```

I've configured the client VPN endpoint to use TCP, since UDP is blocked by firewall in the office I'm working from.

Other than this, all is by the guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html

Nothing is logged to the related CloudWatch Log Group.

How can I further investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and made it work with assistance from their support engineer. Two things to check:

- CA part in ACM client certificate is required (even though it says it's optional)
- Any changes in ACM client certificate are NOT automatically reflected in AWS VPN endpoint referencing that cert. In other words, when you re-import ACM client certificate (e.g. to add CA part) you need to create a new VPN endpoint.

Once I took both of these items into account all soft-resets went away